# A very simple positionning problem using pgfplots standalone geometry and tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, positioning, standalone

I try to find information in the big list of pgfplots question on tex, without success, so this is "one more question" from a beginner about `pgfplots`, `standalone`, `geometry`, `tikz` combo package.

I need to understand two use case to make my thesis :

[image: Simple example]

- (1) How can i centering one graphics on A4 sized paper,
- (2) How can i add multiple graphics on A4 sized paper

I find multiple example using 2 graphics, but my problem use a 3D graphics, and i cannot give only one x width, tikz need to define all : x,y,z . This is a problem, i don't want to enter manually all my graphic dimension ...

In my simple MWE i only try the first option (1), and i have some problem to resize correctly the graphics, i try with `width=\linewidth` to automaticly resize the graphics to the pagesize width without success. Arg, please help me.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.8,
  colormap={whitered}{color(0cm)=(white); color(2cm)=(orange!75!red)}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [view={210}{60},
  width=0.5\linewidth
  ]
  colormap name=whitered
  ]
    \addplot3[surf, draw=black, mesh/ordering=y varies] {x*(1-x)*y*(1-y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`standalone` is meant for producing images that *stand alone* literally. Using `geometry` package and trying to impose `a4paper` is meaning less. You should use one of the standard classes like `article` here. Most possibly, you will be needing a caption for your figure so it makes sense to use the `figure` environment that allows you to put a caption. Then, you can use `\centering` to center the graphic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.8,
  colormap={whitered}{color(0cm)=(white); color(2cm)=(orange!75!red)}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [view={210}{60},
%  width=0.5\linewidth,   %% not needed
  colormap name=whitered ] 
    \addplot3[surf, draw=black, mesh/ordering=y varies] {x*(1-x)*y*(1-y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To put two figures side by side, is a more detailed aspect here that needs more information like do you need separate captions etc. The simplest is to put them like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.8,
  colormap={whitered}{color(0cm)=(white); color(2cm)=(orange!75!red)}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [view={210}{60},
  width=0.5\linewidth,  %% now needed
  colormap name=whitered ] 
    \addplot3[surf, draw=black, mesh/ordering=y varies] {x*(1-x)*y*(1-y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% second graphic↓ don't leave blank line
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [view={210}{60},
  width=0.5\linewidth,  %% now needed
  colormap name=whitered ]
    \addplot3[surf, draw=black, mesh/ordering=y varies] {x*(1-x)*y*(1-y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]